# WilliamChart Axis color & don't start at 0

Tags: android, colors, charts, axis

I'm using the WilliamChart library for Android.
Everything works perfect and now I want to set the axis color to white. I've tried with the following but that didn't change it:

```
chartview:chart_axisColor="#fff"
```

How can I change the axis color?

My second problem is that I have a chart where the numbers are higher than 500 but all about the same. So now I have all the dots of my line on top since the chart starts at 0.
Can WilliamChart figure out my lowest and highest number and fit the points in between?
I think I saw this somewhere but I couldn't find it in the example or the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the color, you're doing it right, so assuming you also defined:

```
xmlns:chartview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

it should work (if not raise the issue on [github](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart)). The sample application has an example of it as well.

If you don't define any minimum and maximum value the library must calculate what they are. Perhaps you are defining them yourself with `setAxisBorderValues` and in that case the lib assumes those as correct.

Comment: The problem was that I added the xmlns part to the parent layout and not to the chartview itself. Thanks!